# What determines the exchange rate for global trade items?

Tags: simcity-buildit

What determines the price of items selling on the global exchange on Sim City Buildit? For example, I see from two different towns a dozer exhaust selling for §799 in one case and §750 in the other. Security cameras range from §490, §505, §559, §650.

Does this also set the price of the goods that I'm selling on the exchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those prices are set by the seller of the item. When you go to the exchange you are given the option to set the price that you're willing to accept for the item.

I've also found that if you set the price too high and no one buys it, eventually the system will buy your item and your selling spot is freed up for you to sell more items.

Comment: I never noticed that... all my slots are full right now, once one of them empties I want to check that out!

Comment: It should be on the right hand side with arrow buttons just below where you change the quantity of the item you are selling.

Comment: I was also going to ask what determines how long it takes items to sell, right now it's been taking forever and sometimes it's really quick, but maybe price has something to do with it.

Comment: It's like any market where price and supply depend on the demand of the item. For example I find manufactured items that are required in other items, tape measure for example, sell quickly, even at max price.